# How to refer to child class in Django REST framework mixin?

Tags: python, django, oop, django-rest-framework, mixins

In Django Rest Framework, I'm trying to write a mixin for the following two methods in view sets:

```
class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # ...
    def get_object(self):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')

        if pk == 'me':
            user = self.request.user
            return get_object_or_404(Order, user=user.pk)

        return super(OrderViewSet, self).get_object()

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Agent.objects.filter(user=user)
```

This seems straight forward except for the `super(OrderViewSet, self)` because I'll need to somehow refer to different viewset classes in my mixin class before they're declared. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use new style super() calling

```
return super().get_object()
```